# link requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: javascript, https

I am pretty new to SSL / https but finally managed to create one for my website

https://thaihome.co.uk

Now the problem is this strange error:

```
app.7e27c5b6c47cfaa5a0da.js:70 error occured for getting the country from: http://freegeoip.net/json/ {data: null, status: -1, config: {…}, statusText: "", headers: ƒ}
app.7e27c5b6c47cfaa5a0da.js:70 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://thaihome.co.uk/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://freegeoip.net/json/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

And its spitting out the error so fast that the browser almost dies.

What does this mean? and what can I do about fixing it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message explains it pretty clearly and tells you exactly what you need to do to fix it.

> Mixed Content

You are mixing content (from HTTPS and HTTP).

> The page at 'https://thaihome.co.uk/'

This is your page.

> was loaded over HTTPS

You said you set it up for HTTPS. It is HTTPS now.

> but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://freegeoip.net/json/'.

And you have some JavaScript which is making an HTTP request using the XMLHttpRequest object.

The URL you are requesting is `http://freegeoip.net/json/` which isn't secure. i.e. it uses HTTP not HTTPS. You can tell because it starts `http:`.

> This request has been blocked;

Because it is insecure, it has been blocked. Otherwise it would inject insecure content into an otherwise secure page. The page wouldn't be secure any more.

> the content must be served over HTTPS.

You need to load it over HTTPS so it is secure before you can load it from your HTTPS page.

Answer (score 2):

It means you need to make the API request to `https://freegeoip.net/json` instead of `http://freegeoip.net/json`

Edit: When you enable SSL on your website, all assets and requests must be made to secure endpoints. Meaning even if you have an image tag that has an unsecured image link going to http like this: `<img src="http://unsecure.com/img.jpeg" />` your browser will not give you the green lock secure symbol. Everything needs to be done over https.